# R - Remove Empty Category in Summary

Tags: r

I'm working on cleaning a dataset I plan to use for analysis. Some records were coded as `''` instead of NA's, so I'm converting all these records to be NA and then dropping them from my dataset.

After dropping these records, the `''` factor group is still showing up in the summary of the data. Is there anyway to fix this?

Example Code:

```
surgery$gender[surgery$gender == ""] <- NA
surgery = surgery %>% drop_na(gender)
surgery$gender = as.factor(surgery$gender)

summary(surgery)
```

Example Summary Output:

[image]

Comment: Please make this more reproducible by including data with `dput`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
surgery$gender = droplevels(surgery$gender)
```